# bipartite graph and dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming, bipartite

I am solving a problem, which has a weighted complete bipartite graph(X,Y,XxY), where X has n nodes and Y has m nodes and n is less than m. I want to have a perfect cross free matching graph, such that no two edges cross while matching set X to set Y and all the nodes in X are taken at the end.The sum of weights of the resulting graph should be minimal, I need to devise a dynammic programming algorithm. This is how I thought of it:

nodes in X and Y are arranged x0, xi can have a horizontal edge to Y0,Yi and so on, but Y has more nodes than X.
For every node in X (i) I consider two options either horizontal neighbor which is j in set Y, or diagonal neighbors (i, j-1), (i,j+1) and choose the edge which minimizes the cost.and I keep track of the nodes in X and Y that are already taken.time complexity O(nm)

Is there a better way I can implement this. Any help is appreciated. This is a question I got in my midterm but I left it in choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `w(x, y)` be edge weight between nodes `x` in `X` and `y` in `Y`, and let `M(i, j)` be solution (minimum cross free matching graph) for vertices `{x_0, x_1, ..., x_i} subset X` and `{y_0, y_1, ..., y_j} subset Y`, where `i < |X|` and `j < |Y|`.

E.g. `M(0, j) = min( w(x_0, y_a) ) for 0 <= a <= j`. `M(i, i-1) = infinity` since there is no matching when 'right' set is smaller.

For `i, j` there are two possibilities: `x_i` is connected to `y_j` or not. Because of that recursion holds:

```
M(i, j) = min( w(i,j) + M(i-1, j-1), M(i, j-1) )
```

Comment: I don't see how this algorithm enforces the cross-free constraint.

Comment: That is due every matching edge is added with w(i,j) + M(i-1, j-1) part, which connects last elements. So adding (every) new edge is 'safe'.

Comment: I think what you're saying is only true if `j >= i` which is not mentioned by the algorithm. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That is covered by intializing M(0, j) = inf, or if you want M(i, j) = inf for i < j. Second initialization is evaluated by recursion and first initialization.